# TYPO3 progress bar while uploading

Tags: upload, progress-bar, typo3

is there any known solution to show a progress bar while uploading big files (5-15 MB) in TYPO3?
The plupload-Extension is not working in Version 6.2

Somehow it should be possible in e.g. jQuery but I don't find a realistic way for that.

Greatings, stefan

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no extension is there in typo3 extension repository.

But there is a way you can mange it with jQuery some few lines of code and bunch of file include.

Checkout the link:
http://designscrazed.org/jquery-css3-progress-bars/

I hope it help you !!!